# Enumerating certain solutions to the equation XAX=B in the Symmetric Group 

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

I'm interested in understanding how to enumerate a certain subset of the solutions to the equation $XAX=B$ in the symmetric group $\Sigma_{n}$. This is related to a topological problem- counting a certain class of $4$-valent graphs on a closed orientable surface, up to homeomorphism of the surface (I'd be happy to be more specific about this if anyone would like).

In general, solutions to $XAX=B$ are of the form $A^{-1}C$, where $C$ is a square root of $AB$.

$\textbf{Broad Question}$: Given $A,B \in \Sigma_{n}$, can one enumerate the solutions to $XAX=B$, such that:
(1) $X$ is an $n$-cycle; (2) $X$ is $\textit{parity reversing}$ ($X$ sends each even number to an odd number)?

After some initial searching, I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer to the broad question, but one can say more in the specific case that I'm interested in: $n$ is of the form $8k-4$, for some $k>2$, and we can write out $AB$ and $A$ explicitly in cycle notation:

$AB= (1,4k+1)(2,4k+2)(3,4k+1)...(4k-4,8k-4)(4k-3,4k-1)(4k-2,4k)$;
$A= (1,4k-1)(2,4k)(3,4k+1)...(4k-2,8k-4)$

Thus, a square root of $AB$ is obtained by pairing off its transpositions, and "interleaving" each pair to create a $4$-cycle. For example, 
$C= (1,2,4k+1,4k+2)(3,4,4k+1,4k+2)....(4k-3,4k-2,4k-1,4k)$ is one such square root. Furthermore, if, as in this example, we pair off the transpositions so that each one containing only odd numbers is paired to one containing only even numbers, then $X=A^{-1}C$ will satisfy condition $(2)$ of the broad question above. We'll call such a square root $C$ $\textit{parity reversing}$, as above.

Therefore we have the following specific question:

$\textbf{Specific question}$: Can one enumerate the parity reversing square roots $C$ of $AB$, such that $A^{-1}C$ is an $(8k-4)$-cycle?

I'm primarily interested in lower bounds, and I suspect these numbers should grow factorially in $k$, at least asymptotically.

Thank you for reading- any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's true, maybe "parity reversing" is a more appropriate term. Originally, there was another formulation of this problem in which I wanted to enumerate the solutions which either send evens to evens, or evens to odds; in either case, mod(2) equivalence is preserved, hence the terminology. 

But in $\Sigma_{n}$ there are no $n$-cycles sending evens to evens, so for this version of the question, we only care about the "mod(2)-equivalence preserving" permutations that send evens to odds. 